# Calling a web service using the script tags

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, asp-classic

My application is built using asp classic and I've tried multiple solutions trying to fix IE 8's Service is not defined issue. The code is below.

tags:

```
 <script language="javascript">
      function init() {
          service.useService("Services/Util.asmx?WSDL", "WebUtil");
      }
  </script>
```

tags:

```
<frameset  onload="init()"  id="service" style="behavior:url(Forms/Behaviors/webservice.htc)"  onresult="ShowResult()" border="1" frameborder="1" framespacing="4" cols='<%= GetFrameColString()%>' topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
```

Note:

The browser can not be updated due to company policy so it has to work in IE 8 and above. And if there are issues with later browsers when calling a webservice this way would help me out as well if the company decides to upgrade IE.

Anyhow can you help with IE 8's stating "service is not defined" issue?

Comment: Did this ever work? Can you even use a `<frameset>` like that?

Comment: Apparently it does. It's working except I have to deal with errors with calling the service correctly. Other than that its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

My original code:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function init() {
      service.useService("Services/Util.asmx?WSDL", "WebUtil");
  }</script>
```

Modified code:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function init() {
      service.useService('Services/Util.asmx?WSDL', 'WebUtil');
  }</script>
```

Apparently it's an syntax error. I assume ASP Classic needs single quotes over double quotes. Right now there is progress in getting my application done.